# Using jQuery serialize to put values into a database select query using AJAX

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following:

```
$allform = $_POST['allform'];
        parse_str($allform, $output);

        $allquery="SELECT * FROM wp_users";
        $names = array();   
        $allresult=mysql_query($allquery) or die(mysql_error()); ?>

        <?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($allresult)){  

            $names[] = $rows['user_email']; 

        }
```

The allform variable is a jQuery serialize string:

```
  var allform = $('form#all').serialize();
```

Basically, I want to put the values from the form in the front end into a mysql select query in the back end.

The form is a bunch of checkboxes so the idea is that the SELECT *something* will have different number of values depending on what the user checks. Im not even sure if the serialize function is worth it here, but I cant think of any thing. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the serialize function only makes sense if you use ajax.
example:

```
$.post("test.php", $("form#all").serialize());
```

test.php would be the url to you php script.
on the PHP side you will be able to handle it the same way as any other form submission, e.g. every form field will be it's own index in the post array

Comment: Yeah I am using the jQuery.ajax, not .post. I just dont know how to get the values in the SELECT query on the server-side..

Comment: as you're posting a form to the server, post would make more sense in your case. then simply print_r the $_POST variable on the server side and you should see all the form fields listed in the array